# .htaccess - Remove all cookies

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, cookies

I want to make an existing domain a "CDN" domain that serves all images, CSS and JS files (i.e. static files). However that domain was parked earlier and some application on that domain has set cookies.

As far as I can observe, I'd say that with cookies the "Expires" header doesn't seem to have much effect with some browsers (Including Firefox). The browsers still request the file, even if they shouldn't do so for the next month.

It would be possible to do some mod_rewrite tricks to detect if there are any cookies and then call a PHP file to remove the cookies and serve the static file so that for the next call there aren't any cookies left, but maybe you can give me a simpler method:

Is there a "Apache .htaccess only" way of removing all existing cookies?

Answer (score 3):

The [Header](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html#header) directive might do the trick.

But I strongly doubt that a stored cookie in Firefox influences cacheing in any way.

Comment: Yeah, this is unlikely to be a cookie issue.

Comment: I think BlaM wants to do something like this: http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/request.html#ServeFromCookielessDomain.

Answer (score 1):

Try :

> ```
> Header unset Set-Cookie
> ```